# Ruby wildcard on path

Tags: ruby

The following ruby code to store a previous URL is meant to exclude a certain series where the resulting action might send the user in an endless loop.

```
  def current_user_url   # store last url 
    if (request.fullpath != "/users/sign_in?locale=*" &&
        request.fullpath != "/users/sign_up?locale=*" &&
        request.fullpath != "/users/password?locale=*" &&
        request.fullpath != "/users/sign_out?locale=*" &&
        request.fullpath != "/users?locale=*" &&
        !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
      session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
    end
  end
```

when handling self-referential actions

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || session[:confirm_url]
end
```

The wildcard character is not working as desired, as the session variable is storing, for example, `/users/sign_in?locale=en`  notwithstanding the use of the wildcard. *note: without the use of `?locale=en` the function does work as expected.*

How can this code become locale agnostic?

**Update with note on solution**

In case anyone drops by and is flustered by the [second apporach of a wiki for the devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update), you're not alone.  I wasn't too thrilled instinctively with an after filter.  Digging into Devise's store location method is an option, though not as straightforward as Max's solution below.

That does need a slight tweak though *(and [ahem, yes] the question did not mention devise)* where routes need to invoke `devise_for` and the controller needs to inherit from devise

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations', sessions: 'sessions' } 

class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_action :store_location 
end
```

This feels cleaner to me come maintenance time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `request.full_path` you can use `request.path` which does not include the query string.

But a better solution altogether is just skipping the callback on the effected controllers / actions as this distributes the responsibilities correctly.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :store_location
  def store_location
    session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
  end 
end

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :store_location
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :store_location, only: :index
end
```

Comment: a wise approach; yes, I appreciate the distribution of responsibilities.  I also send a kudo for the succinctness!

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards don't work in string comparisons, which are just straight character-by-character equality checks.

You need to use a regular expression, and check for a [`match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match), or use [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
if (!request.fullpath[%r{\A/users/sign_in\?locale=.*\z}] &&
  ...
```

Comment: And by using a regex you now you have two problems... :). The first one is that the pattern does not match `/users/sign_in` without a locale. The second is that it does not match `/users/sign_in.html`.